# Unity first release was debug and was successfully uploaded on Play Store. Second release gave error. Why?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I created a game in Unity and uploaded it in the Google Play Store. I kept the Unity Publishing Settings like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88dpV.png), built the game and then uploaded it. 
Later, I edited my game and built it again using the exact same publishing settings but I changed the version and bundle version to 2.0. While uploading the APK, I got the error:

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode.

I really need to know what to do now.
I can't delete my game from play store.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you rebuilt the game did you put in your password for your signing your APK?

Comment: I did that but then I got this error:Upload failed

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.

Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 89:2F:11:FE:CE:D6:CC:DF:65:E7:76:3E:DD:A7:96:4F:84:DD:BA:33 ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 20:26:F4:C1:DF:0F:2B:D9:46:03:FF:AB:07:B1:28:7B:9C:75:44:CC ]

Comment: No option remaining. Change Package and first **Sign the App** and than release.
Don't Release **Debug** Build.

Comment: So you mean I cannot add an update to the game?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, just started a few days ago. More info here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/publish-update-failed-android-playmarket.543793/

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the same keystore that you selected the first time you uploaded your app. The error message suggests that you either selected a different one, or used the alias of a different key in the keystore.

If you have lost that keystore or the alias/password of the key in the keystore, then you have to create a new app if you're *not* enrolled in App Signing by Play, or if you are, then you can contact Google Play to [reset your key](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB).

Comment: I never created that key. As I said I uploaded as debug and it uploaded successfully. If I never created the key How can I reset it?

Comment: This is a regression in the Play Console. It should allow you to update. We'll fix it shortly. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @Pierre can I track the status of the bug somewhere ?. need to update my app on the play console

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Think something weird has happened with Google Plays auto App signing, I'm having the same issue:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/publish-update-failed-android-playmarket.543793/